# Dynamic Text Snippets?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text, snippets

Suppose my snippet is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
1example \> 
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>1e</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
</snippet>
```

and suppose I need several other similar snippets:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
2example \> 
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>2e</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
</snippet>
```

Is it possible to define the snippet in such a way that, say `[some_number]e` triggers the snippet and it expands like `[some_number]example`?

Comment: Instead of `1e` -> `1example`, just have `e` -> `example`

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no way to do this in a standard snippet. I can think of these two options:

1. You handle the snippet part in Python ([Example](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/ColourComplete/blob/master/colourcomplete.py#L3))
2. You extend [Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/) [snippets](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) with Latex support